# Pyside6 AttributeError in custom signal

Tags: toolbar, signals-slots, pyside6

In this minimal code, I'm trying to return a value from an event after pressing a button on the Toolbar.

"connection_established" is the signal connected to connection_status()
and connected_button emits the signal

but I receive this error:

`self.toolbar_m.connection_established.connect(self.connection_status) AttributeError`

I have double-checked many times, and the logic seems correct to me
but, of course, something is wrong

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QToolBar)
from PySide6.QtGui import QAction, QIcon
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Signal
from PySide6 import QtCore

QtCore.QDir.addSearchPath('icon', 'icon/')


class ToolBar:
    connection_established = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        toolbar = QToolBar("toolbar")
        toolbar.setIconSize(QSize(16, 16))

        connect_action = QAction(QIcon('icon:icons8_connect_50.png'), "&Connect", self.parent)
        connect_action.triggered.connect(self.connect_button)
        toolbar.addAction(connect_action)
        toolbar.addSeparator()
        self.parent.addToolBar(toolbar)

    def connect_button(self):
        self.connection_established.emit(True)


class Tele(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tele, self).__init__()
        self.toolbar_m = ToolBar(self)
        self.toolbar_m.connection_established.connect(self.connection_status)

    def connection_status(self, connected):
        if connected:
            print("Connected")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    tele = Tele()
    tele.show()
    app.exec()
```

It should return the boolean value emitted by connected_button

I am trying to return a value from an event of a toolbar object and use it in the main class Tele()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Toolbar` class is a regular python object. In order to use signals it should inherit from `QObject`.

```
from PySide6.QtCore import QSize, Signal, QObject    

class ToolBar(QObject):
    connection_established = Signal(bool)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # rest of the code
```

Comment: ...............Yes  Thank you